# What formatting setting could be causing this indent within the table cell?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, text-formatting, indentation

I am creating a resume using Microsoft word with the table as my means for structure. I am seeing some weird indents taking place within one of the cell, what could be the cause of this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your ruler, it looks like the Hanging Indent (bottom triangular) marker is to the right of the First Line Indent (top triangular) marker